# How to find ID from a table based on user selection

Tags: php, mysql

So I am creating some php code for the add accommodation section of my website. The user is given the option of selecting a city from the drop down menu (the list is retrieved from the city table in the mysql database by using a simple query and echo). But what needs to be stored in the add accomodation table is the city ID and of course I can't be asking the user for that! What I can't figure out is how to query the city table using the selected city and retrieve the city ID from the same table and store that in the accommodation table in the backend database. Here is the code I have so far.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT City_Name FROM Cities";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<p>
<label for = "City_Name" class = "fixed_required">City: </label>
<select name="select_City" id="select_City" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['City_Name'])) echo $_POST['City_Name']; ?>"/>
</p>
<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['City_Name'];?>"> <?php echo $line['City_Name'];?> </option>
<?php
```

Comment: You should switch from City Name to the City_ID in the option value attribute, and then after posting the form get the ID from the option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Once I make that switch, is there any more code needed or will that do it?

Comment: Ofcourse. you need to get the data you've just posted from the $_POST var and query the database with the id you've just recived.
 TIP: use mysqli - instead of mysql. its deprecated and not safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
value="<?php echo $line['City_ID'];?>"
```

and change your query to include the ID :

```
$query = "SELECT City_Name, City_ID FROM Cities";
```

**EDITED :**

Ok...you also need to set up the "SELECTED" attribute base on `$_POST['select_City']` on the OPTION tag and remove the `value="<?php if(isset($_POST['City_Name'])) echo $_POST['City_Name']; ?>"` on the `SELECT` tag....And like @Dan Revah suggested, use MYSQLI instead since mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT City_Name, City_ID FROM Cities";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<p>
<label for = "City_Name" class = "fixed_required">City: </label>
<select name="select_City" id="select_City" />
</p>
<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['City_ID'];?>"  
<?php
if(isset($_POST['select_City'])) { 
    if(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select_City'])==$line['City_ID']) { 
       echo "selected"
    }
}?>
>
<?php echo $line['City_Name'];?> </option>
<?php
```

Comment: @dan08 Thanks...I didn't see that the query was also in the code :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses, I'm really stuck! So I've made the changes as listed above including adding CITY_ID to the query. Is there anything else need?

Comment: Look my `EDITED` part

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Just reading through this now and I want to ensure that I understand it correctly. So it will query for both City_name and City_ID, Show the user the list of cities and once they select one, it will match it with its City_ID and place just the City_ID in the add accommodation table and not the City_name.

Comment: You will have the City_ID value in `$_POST['select_City']`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I have all the variables declared at the top so I have $City_ID = $_POST['select_City']; and then a huge insertion query with $City_ID being one of the inputs.

Comment: Don't forget `mysql_real_escape_string` at least or you will be wide open to SQL injection...`$City_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select_City']);` ... and I suggest that you start to learn `MYSQLI` or `PDO` since `MYSQL_` commands are deprecated...